# Implementing Custom Codec with JSR-135 MMAPI

Tags: java-me, codec, mmapi

Is it possible to implement a custom codec decoder and play a media file using [JSR135](http://java.sun.com/javame/reference/apis/jsr135/)? Actually I am interested in playing back a custom media file in J2ME. I think JSR135 is a good starting point but I am open to other suggestions. Thanks.

**Update**
I have not tried but I believe, if I open the file using JSR75 I will get an InputStream. I can use a custom InputStream that converts the custom codec to a known codec that MMAPI will understand and I can playback. However it would be better if I can do without using JSR75 and many security warnings that will come with it.

Comment: where do you get the audio data from if not JSR75? in-Jar, RMS, HTTP?

Comment: MMAPI supports 3 factory methods to create a player. One of them is using a remote connection, one of them is providing an InputStream (jsr75 or in jar resource) or providing a file name. In case of providing a file name MMAPI opens and plays the file as it natively. I hope this answers your question.

Comment: Even if you write the codec successfully, playing it on the device might not be possible on the device, as far as I know, J2ME does not provide sucn an interface

Comment: It will be interesting to know if this is possible in J2ME.